# Multiple calls to static httpclient hangs console application

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I noticed when I use a single static instance of HttpClient, my code hangs, and exits a few minutes later with an error - simply says one of the tasks was cancelled with no specific error given.

```
    static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var t1 = _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");
            t1.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("complete");
            var t2 = _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");
            t2.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("complete");
            var t3 = _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");
            t3.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("complete");
            var t4 = _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");
            t4.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("complete");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

When I switch to the following code and create separate instances of the HttpClient, the problem goes away.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient();
            var t1 = client1.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");
            t1.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("complete");
            HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient();
            var t2 = client2.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");
            t2.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("complete");
            HttpClient client3 = new HttpClient();
            var t3 = client3.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");
            t3.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("complete");
            HttpClient client4 = new HttpClient();
            var t4 = client4.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");
            t4.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("complete");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

I would like to know first why this is happening, and if there is a way to safely use the static HttpClient multiple times as I have in the first block of code (not necessary, just out of curiosity)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you use the "GetStreamAsync" method. If you call this method multiple with one instance, the "_client" opens the same stream multiple and copy this stream to "t1", "t2", ... You create a deadlock with this open streams. You should use "GetStringAsync" or you should close the stream "t1", before "_client" opens a stream for "t2" and so on. The following code shows, how you can do this:

```
class Program
{
    private static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var t1 = _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"))
            {
                t1.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("complete");
            }

            using (var t2 = _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"))
            {
                t2.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("complete");
            }

            using (var t3 = _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"))
            {
                t3.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("complete");
            }

            using (var t4 = _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"))
            {
                t4.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("complete");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I added a simple using, that calls automatically the dispose method of "t1", if the programm leaving the using block of "t1".

Additionally I recommend, that you use "await" to work cleanly with async code. The problem, that you can't use "await" in your code, is that the "Main" method can't to be made to an async method. But you can handle this, with create a new async void method like the following:

```
class Program
{
    private static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        GetStreamsAsync();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async void GetStreamsAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var t1 = await _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("complete");
            }

            using (var t2 = await _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("complete");
            }

            using (var t3 = await _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("complete");
            }

            using (var t4 = await _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("complete");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

You have to call the "Console.ReadKey" method in the "Main" method, because the "Main" method is done before the new "async void GetSteamsAsync" method.

UPDATE (Thanks to Stuart for the comment):
If you use other app models, it is recommended to use "ConfigureAwait" as well. It doesn't make sense to use "ConfigureAwait" in a console application, because there is no SynchronizationContext to capture and continue on.

Comment: Nice. The `ConfigureAwait(false)` advice is redundant in a console app, as there is no SynchronizationContext to capture and continue on. In other app models it would be essential advice however, or in a library good practice.

Comment: The first variation runs into the same problem I had originally, it completes the first and second task then hangs for a minute or two and the exception is thrown.  The second variation works perfect. I think the first would be more like                `using (HttpClient _client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var t1 = _client.GetStreamAsync("http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");
                    t1.Wait();
                    Console.WriteLine("complete");
                }`

Comment: I have tested both variations and both works for me. But as I recommended the second solution is the better one. I'm glad, that I could help. Can you please mark my answer as "accepted"?